# Unable to get the values from the datagridview to textboxes

Tags: c#, datagridview

Greetings!
            In my project there is a requirement for me that if I click on datagridviewcell, it should popup the values into the text boxes in the form, actually it is working sometimes and sometimes not working, not knowing what the wrong I am doing, it is like, on the third click it is not working. The code which I am using is:

```
private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int i = dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

    txtPrjNmae.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    txtPrjdescription.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    txtPrjDate.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
    txtPrjSize.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    txtPrjManager.Text = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString();           
}
```

Comment: why don't you use `e.RowIndex` instead of `dataGridView2.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Break point to check and To Set

```
int i = e.RowIndex;
```